# PhpStorm Git not connecting through the general proxy

Tags: git, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

After set proxy at the general proxy setting of PhpStorm, ssh git not connecting and errors:

> Ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists

But with the same settings, PyCharm works.

Git server is BitBucket.

Comment: What type of proxy type do you have, SOCKS or HTTP? Do you have any authentication on your proxy?

Comment: HTTP and SOCKS both i can use, neither work, there is no authentication